# How do you breed horses?

Tags: pocket-stables

I'm currently in year 6 in Pocket Stables and I just can't get my horses to breed.

Can someone explain the process to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it how to unlock breeding,

You have to beat 16 Mile race, Which gives you G III which, unlocking Breeding. To use breeding, You can go to: Menu > Actions > Breeding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to beat more races first before you can start breeding. I believe you have to beat the 16 Mile race first.